# default argument or function overload

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a function `pop` with one argument, that pops elements out of a stack. I want to be able to use `pop()`, which will remove one element from the top; and `pop(any_number)`, which will pop multiple elements from the top.  One thing got me curious about a trivial implementation detail.

function overloading:

```
void pop() {
   if(!stack.empty())
     stack.pop();
}

void pop(int n) {
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      pop();
}
```

function default argument:

```
void pop(int n = 1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      if(!stack.empty())
         stack.pop();
}
```

Is there difference other than the simpler code in the latter one. Is there advantage on using the first on or the second one?

EDIT: changed the first snippet to be more reusable design-wise by replacing the for loop with scope with `pop` function.

Comment: I think when you need really often to do a `pop()`, then the second version could be a little bit slower then the first one, because of the for-loop (more code, more data)...

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise: it doesn't matter. The compiler is smart enough to generate code that is efficient in both cases, for most applications. Some may argue that the second version, in the case of a call to `pop()`, an extra `for` loop would be generated. This can actually be trivially optimized by the compiler.

As far as readability is concerned, the second is definitely more expressive. But in the end it really comes down to preference. Choose the one you think fits best your design, and remember not to pre-optimize.